# R: loop not inputting correct indexes

Tags: r, for-loop, rselenium

I scraped a bunch of url's and was using RSelenium to add the links to the archive.org website. My loop was about half way finished when it broke. So I used the `which()` function to determine where it left off, then I restarted the loop from that point.

The problem is that the driver kept typing the wrong index instead of the one I specified in the loop. To fix the problem, I subset 'mget_links' to 'mget_links2' so that it only contained the remaining links I needed. I ran the loop again and it somehow still typed an index from 'mget_links'. The driver keeps typing in this link: https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053146

What is going on here? How do I fix it?

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium); library(netstat)

pageMen = read_html('https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories')

mget_links <- pageMen %>% 
  html_nodes('.categories-grid__category a') %>% 
  html_attr('href') %>%
  paste0('https://www.bjjcompsystem.com', .)

# know the length for the loop
length(mget_links)

remote_driver = rsDriver(browser = 'firefox',
                         verbose = F,
                         port = free_port())
rd = remote_driver$client
rd$open()
rd$navigate('https://web.archive.org/save')
rd$maxWindowSize()

for (i in 1:length(mget_links[255:259])){
  save_page_box = rd$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//*[(@id = "web-save-url-input")]')
  save_page_box$clickElement()
  save_page_box$sendKeysToElement(list(mget_links[i], key='enter'))
Sys.sleep(26)

return.to.save.page = rd$findElement(using = 'link text', 'Return to Save Page Now')
return.to.save.page$clickElement()
}

# Reran above code with mget_links2 instead of mget_links[255:259]. I also tried #mget_links2[1:156] with no luck.
mget_links2= mget_links[104:259]
```

Comment: In your for loop you are using `i in 1:length(mget_links[255:259]`, which will return 1:5, but then subsetting using mget_links[i], so you will be looking at the first 5 elements - is that what you're meaning to do? It looks like you might be wanting to using `i in 255:259`, or change how you're subsetting `mget_links` within the for loop?

Comment: Aha! using `255:259` instead of `1:length(mget_links[255:259]` did the trick, thanks!! I have tried this various ways (except the one you suggested. `i in length(mget_links[255:259]` only ran the loop once and `i in mget_links[255:259]` did not work. Why did they not work? and why does `1:length(mget_links[255:259]` not start at element 255?

Comment: If you look at `mget_links[255:259]`, what you are doing is taking a subset of `mget_links`, from the 255th index to the 259th index, so you are left with a vector that is 5 elements long. So when you use `length()` to get the length of this subset, it returns 5 and i iterates from 1 to 5. With `i in mget_links[255:259]`, you are returning the element itself rather than an index, so where you have `mget_links[i]` in the for loop you could replace it with `i` and it would work, because you wouldn't need to index the vector if you are just iterating over the elements themselves.

Comment: That's how I figured it worked, but using the subset still returned the first link in the original, mget_links.